# Is there a way to set/cap a "maximum" "Task" Virtual Desktop in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

Currently, if you have 2 Vitual Desktop, Ctrl + Win + Arrow Left will create you a new one if you are already on the last one, instead of "Cylcing" to the first Desktop.

Is there a way to have it Cycle to the First Desktop or set a hard cap of how many you can open.
I only need 2 Desktops maximum at any time.

Comment: Doesn't happen to me. Check if it's happening when booting in Safe mode, to find if this is caused by some installed product.

Comment: I just checked, It was just some weird thing that happened a few times. checked in Safemode, it doens't reopen new deskstops & did a clean reboot and it didn't either.

Comment: It's rare, but it happens. I added an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was fixed by booting into Safe mode and then
returning to normal boot.

This a rare case, but it does happen that some Windows software was
unblocked by the boot in Safe mode and could then resolve its own problem.